# Angular Material Grid List - How to dynamically add a new grid tile

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a dashboard containing a number of components displayed as angular material cards within a material grid list. e.g.

```
<mat-grid-tile *ngFor="let c of mainComponents" [colspan]="( cardLayout | async )?.components?.cols" [rowspan]="( cardLayout | async )?.components?.rows">
      <app-dashboard-card [title]="c.title">
          <app-line-chart></app-line-chart>
      </app-dashboard-card>
   </mat-grid-tile>
```

I want to be able to push an additional component/card to the list e.g.

```
onAddComponentClick() {
    this.componentsAdded = this.componentsAdded + 1;
    let newComponent = { title: "New Component " + this.componentsAdded.toString(), type: "chart"};
    this.mainComponents.push(newComponent);
  }
```

How do I effectively re-render the list so the new component is displayed when added to the collection, similarly if I was to remove an item from the collection?

Answer (score 0):

I have never done that before, but I have created other components dynamically, so I have some idea. This is how I think it works:

Firts add a references to the grid:

```
@ViewChild(MatGridList) gridList: MatGridList;
```

Then this is the function to add a new tile:

```
addNewTile() {
    const newTile = { cols: 1, rows: 1, text: 'New Tile' };

    this.tiles.push(newTile);

    this.gridList._updateCols();
}
```

And this is the html component:

```
<mat-grid-list cols="2" rowHeight="100px">
    <mat-grid-tile *ngFor="let tile of tiles" [colspan]="tile.cols" [rowspan]="tile.rows">
        {{ tile.text }}
   </mat-grid-tile>
</mat-grid-list>

<button (click)="addNewTile()">Add Tile</button>
```

I hope this help you